# Vertical alignment in latex table

Tags: tables

Question: How can i adjust vertical alignment of numbers in latex table?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=0.60in, right=0.60in, top=0.60in, bottom=0.60in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \Huge
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        $x$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\ \hline
        $y$ & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the vertical alignment you're after for the numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `cellspace` package, which lets you define *minimal* vertical spacing between the top of a row and the above cell, or between the bottom and the below cell. Note the values of the adjustment is obtained by trial and errors, and depends on the font.

However, note that in this case, other glyphs won't be vertically centred, if they have no ascenders (like `x`), or no ascenders, but have descenders (like `y`). All we have is lining numbers and capital letters are vertically centred.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=0.60in]{geometry}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\renewcommand\cellspacetoplimit{9.5pt}

\begin{document}

    \Huge
    \begin{tabular}{|*{6}{Sc|}}
        \hline
        $x$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
        $y$ & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

like this?

[image]

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \Huge
\setlength\extrarowheight{.25ex}   % <--- added
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        $x$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\ \hline
        $y$ & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

However, observe "y" in the first column. Is it centered?

Comment: yes x and y both are centered

Comment: If i am not wrong, space above and below the numbers are not equal.

Comment: @snehal I think that you are wrong: I measured Zarko's image and the space above and below the numbers is the same. The space below the `y` is, of course, different because it is meant to go below the line. I am not sure why some one has given Zarko a down-vote because he has answered the question. The question doesn't give very much information as to what is actually required, so I suspect that the problem is due to the vagueness of the question, rather than with this solution (see Werner's comment).

Comment: So sorry, now i understand

Comment: Fully agreed with all given answers